# Read a line after specific word using c#

Tags: c#

I am attempting to parse a text file and have encountered a problem.  I needed to read a line after the word "MESSAGE".

The file would contain sample data like the following.

MESSAGE 
    2005 Repair auto axle driver side.

MESSAGE 
    1508 Repair hydrolic suspension.

In this case I wanted to read the lines beginning with 2005 and 1508.

Here is my code

```
List<Record> records = new List<Record>();

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("SampleData.txt", FileMode.Open)) 
{
    using (StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        string tempreadline;
        tempreadline = rdr.ReadLine();
        while (tempreadline != null)
        {
            if (tempreadline.Contains("MESSAGE")
               {
                     // what do I do here?
                     // skip "MESSAGE" line and read the next line
               }
        }
     }
}
```

Any suggestions?  Thank you!

Comment: Is all of this given to you in a string? Do you have a stream you have to parse on the fly? More info is needed. If you have the string in memory already you can just `Split` it by `"MESSAGE"`.

Comment: You should add some code to explain what you have tried. Are you reading a text file from a log?

Comment: Split the string at linebreak using regex.  In c#:
string[] arrAnswer= Regex.Split(paragraph, "\r\n");
    var theAnswer = arrAnswer[1];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**METHOD 1**

Using your approach.

```
Console.WriteLine("METHOD 1");

var records = new List<string>();

using (var fs = new FileStream("d:\\SampleData.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (var rdr = new StreamReader(fs))
    {
        var msgFound = false;
        while (!rdr.EndOfStream)
        {
            var tempreadline = rdr.ReadLine();
            if (tempreadline.Contains("MESSAGE"))
            {
                msgFound = true;
            }
            else if (msgFound && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempreadline))
            {
                records.Add(tempreadline);
                msgFound = false;
            }
        }
    }
}

records.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r));
```

**METHOD 2**

Assuming your text is a single string.

```
Console.WriteLine("METHOD 2");

var text = File.ReadAllText("d:\\SampleData.txt");
records = text.Split(new[] { "MESSAGE" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              .Select(t => t.Trim(' ', '\r', '\n'))
              .Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
              .ToList();

records.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r));
```

**METHOD 3**

Assuming your text is a list of strings.

```
Console.WriteLine("METHOD 3");

var texts = File.ReadLines("d:\\SampleData.txt");
records = texts.Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t) && !t.StartsWith("MESSAGE"))
               .ToList();

records.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r));
```

**METHOD 4**

Using regular expressions.

```
Console.WriteLine("METHOD 4");

records = new Regex(@"^MESSAGE[\s]*$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline)
                .Split(text)
                .Select(t => t.Trim(' ', '\r', '\n'))
                .Where(t => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t))
                .ToList();

records.ForEach(r => Console.WriteLine(r));
```

Comment: I tried your method and it returned with error on the MESSAGE with this message.  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char'.

Comment: my fault, was answering with my mobile. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.  I still get similar error this time on new [ ] {"MESSAGE"} -- cannot convert 'string[]' to 'char'

Comment: Sorry again, now a tested answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the desired content is in a file, you could use a combination of the `File.ReadAllLines` method, which is described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx), and a Linq extension method, as follows. The array `DesiredLines` can the be processed further.

```
var DesiredLines = File.ReadAllLines("C:\FileName.txt")
                       .Where( iLine => iLine != "MESSAGE" && iLine != "")
                       .ToArray();
```